# MATLAB "element-wise" logical indexing

Tags: matlab, indexing

Suppose I have an array

```
d1 = 0 : 0.5 : 10
```

(d1 represents a discretization of a random variable, FWIW.) Suppose I have another array, e.g.,

```
d2 = [0.35 pi 4.2731]
```

Now I want an array that gives me the index of the closest element in d1 to each element in d2 -- actually I'd even take the largest element in d1 that is less than the element of d2, i.e., I want

```
ind = [2 8 10]
```

How can I do this efficiently? If I only needed this for a single element of d2, I could do something like

```
dindex = 1:length(d1);
ind = min(dindex(d1 >= d2(3)))
```

But if I want to do it for all elements in d2, I can't say `ind = min(dindex(d1 >= d2))`. What's the solution? And thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might prefer faster and vectorized approach with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
[~,ind] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus,d1,d2')),[],2)
```

Comment: It's so much FUN using `bsxfun`!

Comment: @Shai Can't agree more :)

Comment: Faster to write, but not to run.

Comment: Challenging `bsxfun` for `repmat`?  Are you sure? :)

Comment: I don't think this works because d1 and d2 might not have the same dimension, which bsxfun requires.

Comment: @grendelsdad Note the `transpose` sign on `d2`, with which the `bsxfun` maps into a 2D matrix of the `subtraction` values between `d1` and `d2`. Did you try the code?

Comment: @Divakar `bsxfun` basically uses `repmat` as indirectly implied in its manual.

Comment: @Jigg Link me to that manual? As far as I know `bsxfun` uses JIT and it appears `repmat` uses looping.

Comment: @Divakar you're probably right. The manual says that `bsxfun` tiles the array with the smallest dimension to match the bigger one, which sounds a lot like `repmat`. In this specific case, with the example given by OP, the `repmat` approach is faster (although in the same order of magnitude).

Comment: @Jigg I have done benchmarks with big datasizes and `bsxfun` is 3x better than `repmat` on runtime. I can provide actual numbers if you are interested. I think you can try benchmarking too :)

Comment: @Divakar yep, I benchmarked with the example given by OP: `bsxfun`: 0.000364 seconds, `repmat`: 0.000165 seconds.

Comment: @Jigg Try something bigger than only three elements for benchmarking? Try these - `d1 = 0 : 0.005 : 10; d2 = 0 : 0.003:10;`

Comment: @Divakar oops I missed the transpose, sorry about that. Now I've tried the code and it seems to produce the same results, and faster than the repmat approach: 5.381s vs. 9.251s over 4008 calls. Thanks.

Comment: @grendelsdad Yes `bsxfun` involves a bit of learning curve for sure. Keep using it! Thank you for getting some benchmark figures!

Comment: @Divakar note that my comment said 'In this specific case, with the example given by OP, …'. But I'm with you on larger datasets.

Answer (score 1):

On second thought, since d1 has equally-spaced elements, I think a cleaner way is this:

```
dlo = d1(1);
dhi = d1(length(d1));
ddelta = d1(2) - d1(1);

ind = round((min(dhi, max(dlo, d2)) - dlo) / ddelta) + 1;
```

(The min and max ensure d2 entries are within the range of d1.) This is a lot faster -- 0.038s on my 4008 calls.

Thanks everyone...this was quite a positive first experience on this site.

Comment: Neat, I would go for appropriate indexing before any other function.